# How can I host a React webpack project with React Router 4 onto OpenShift?

Tags: reactjs, redux, webserver, openshift, hosting

I'm currently try to find the best way to host React/Webpack application using React Router.

Can I use node express to do that?

My first solution was to use the route (*) server side, letting the client logic of my application handling the routing

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});
```

and my `index.html` file has simple this structure :

```
<html>
   <body id='react-root'></body>
   <script src='bundle.js' />
</html>
```

Are there any better solution(s)?